# Transform an M[A => B] to an A => M[B]

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

Does there exist a utility in Scala or Scalaz to transform a container/collection of functions to a function that maps from the same input to a collection output values? The signature would look something like

```
def transform[M[_], A, B](m: M[A => B]): A => M[B] = ???
```

Here's an example implementation for the List container:

```
def transform[A, B](fs: List[A => B]): A => List[B] = x =>
  fs.foldRight[List[B]](Nil) {
    (f, acc) => f(x) :: acc
  }
```

Ideally, this would work for any function container, including a tuple of functions, an `Option[Function1[A, B]]`, or even a `TupleN[Option[Function1[A, B]], ...]`.

EDIT:

I've just realized that (at least for the special case of a List) the map function works:

```
    def transform[A, B](fs: List[A => B]): A => List[B] = x => fs map (_(x))
```

This can generalize to anything that has a map function with the appropriate semantics. What's the appropriate type class for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `M` is a Functor, `mapply` in scalaz's `Functor` has a similar type signature:

```
def mapply[A, B](a: A)(f: F[A => B]): F[B] = map(f)((ff: A => B) => ff(a))
```

So you could write transform in terms of that:

```
def transform[M[_],A,B](m: M[A => B])(implicit f:Functor[M]):A => M[B] = f.mapply(_)(m)
```

Edit: Another implementation using features from `FunctorSyntax`:

```
def transform[M[_]:Functor,A,B](m: M[A => B]):A => M[B] = _.mapply(m)
```

Comment: Interesting. I just discovered Functor and added an answer below. Is there any benefit to using `mapply` rather than `map`?

Comment: They are two different functions, however, `mapply` can be written in terms of `map`. If you change `fs` to `f` and expand the placeholder in your implementation, you'll see it's essentially the same implementation as `mapply`: `f map ((ff: A => B) => ff(a))`, compared to `map(f)((ff: A => B) => ff(a))`

Comment: My previous comment was written in response to "what's the difference between `map` and `mapply`", which is how I remember your original comment was worded. The benefit is code reuse (see the edit). `transform` is essentially `mapply` with the arguments rearranged.

Comment: Yes, I reworded it to make what I was actually asking more clear. In particular, I did not like the verbosity of explicitly adding the argument list for the Functor but I did like how it more closely approximated a point-free style. Your latest edit is definitely the cleanest and clearest implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I searched through the Scalaz source code and it looks like `Functor` does the trick:

```
def transform[M[_]: Functor, A, B](fs: M[A => B]): A => M[B] = a => fs map (_(a))
```